# How can I use the Commerce Paypal module module without the Commerce module?

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I have a form, which has an amount and item detail values to pass to PayPal.

I have installed the [Commerce Paypal](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) module, but I don't find any clue on how to integrate it so that when the form is submitted, it should go to PayPal for transaction. On success, it should redirect to the success URL; likewise, it should happen on failure, where the users are redirected to  the failure URL. I haven't installed the [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module as there is no use of pages like catalogs and checkout in this system.

How can I use the Commerce Paypal module?

Comment: You can use it as a code donor for your own module ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commerce Paypal has the following dependencies:

- commerce
- commerce_ui
- commerce_payment
- commerce_order

Installing/using Commerce Paypal *without* Drupal Commerce isn't possible; it's a supplemental payment module, and requires Commerce's API to work.

You may instead be interested in something like [Webform Paypal](https://drupal.org/project/webform_paypal)

> The Webform Paypal module sends the user to Paypal to complete a payment whenever they submit a webform containing the component on your site.

Comment: So how can I work the commercepaypal module after installing all those associated modules . . I have no idea how can I use that module in my system

Comment: o . . k . . let me try that module first

Comment: I'm afraid no-one here will be able to tell you how to use and set up an entire Drupal Commerce site, it's much too broad a subject for our Q+A site. There are many, many tutorials out there, though. [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+commerce+tutorial&oq=drupal+commerce+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5437j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: i did research on google and found nothing so i placed question here . . but still i don't get a clue for my system . . Well for the dynamic system i can't just register paypal button . . so the Webform Paypal module still not a good option . .

Comment: Sorry but I find it hard to believe you've found nothing. The link to the Google search I posted in the last comment has literally dozens of tutorials to set up Drupal Commerce. There's no easy solution here, you need to put the time and effort in

Comment: well i wasn't talking about drupalcommerce . . just wanted to integrate ecommerce solution for normal drupal . .

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what Drupal Commerce does. As you specifically said you've installed Commerce Paypal, and haven't installed the Commerce module, I made the assumption you'd already done due diligence on your available options. Again, spend some time on Google to find your options (generally speaking it's Drupal Commerce v Ubercart, the former being the preferred solution these days). Install both solutions, read some tutorials, play with the test site, etc. That's the only way you'll know if an existing solution will work, or if you need to custom code your own.

Comment: @coosal This question is very specific: "How can I use the Commerce Paypal module without installing the Drupal Commerce module?" The answer given from Clive is correct: He told you you cannot have the former module without the latter, and he suggested you a possible module. Now, asking how to set the Drupal Commerce module in comments makes them off-topic; it would be as asking a question about how to cook _eggs and bacon_, and then ask in comments about preparing waffles. Also, Clive suggested an alternative module, which is already something extra.

Comment: @coosal Even asking for an alternative module is a different question, and for that you should ask another question, after you searched on Drupal.org for Paypal payment modules.